# After "pod try Crashlytics", github asks for login and password, but fails every time

Tags: github, cocoapods

I try to run the command "pod try Crashlytics", but Github always asks for authentication. 
Even typing the right password, I'm keeping getting this error.

`$ pod try Crashlytics --verbose`

Updating spec repositories

Updating spec repo `.git`
Username for 'https://github.com': brunodeandrade
Password for 'https://brunodeandrade@github.com': 
[!] CocoaPods was not able to update the `.git` repo. If this is an unexpected issue and persists you can inspect it running `pod repo update --verbose`

/Users/brahdlu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:114:in `rescue in update_git_repo'
/Users/brahdlu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:105:in`update_git_repo'
/Users/brahdlu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:344:in `update'
/Users/brahdlu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:88:in`block (2 levels) in update'
/Users/brahdlu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/brahdlu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:87:in`block in update'
/Users/brahdlu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:86:in `each'
/Users/brahdlu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:86:in`update'
/Users/brahdlu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-try-1.1.0/lib/pod/command/try.rb:217:in `block in update_specs_repos'
/Users/brahdlu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in`section'
/Users/brahdlu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-try-1.1.0/lib/pod/command/try.rb:216:in `update_specs_repos'
/Users/brahdlu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-try-1.1.0/lib/pod/command/try.rb:79:in`setup_spec_in_sandbox'
/Users/brahdlu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-try-1.1.0/lib/pod/command/try.rb:47:in `run'
/Users/brahdlu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in`run'
/Users/brahdlu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/brahdlu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/bin/pod:55:in`'
/Users/brahdlu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/Users/brahdlu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/pod:22:in`'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the problem. 
It was a proxy error, my network was blocking the request.